# Emailing photos in iOS 5.0.1

Tags: ios, applications, email, photos, crash

I have been trying to send an email with a picture attached from the Photo app on my iPhone 3GS, but every time I hit the option button for the photo the app crashes. Its been frustrating. Does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Does it still do this after rebooting the phone?

Comment: Corrupted photo (or photo library) on the device. I'd resync first-and remove photos, then reinstall them. If that fails, restore the device.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be in 1 of 2 areas.  Either there is a problem with the photograph, or it is a problem with your Mail setup.

You can test both areas, try sending a different photo, see if it works.  Or, try sharing the same photo via another mechanism, e.g. messages, or Twitter, see if that works.

If one of them fails, then that is your likely cuprit.  If they both work, then it's likely to be a little more nuanced and harder to track down!